# Terminating string gathered from unpack

Tags: python

I have the following code to grab a string from a binary file.

```
value = struct.unpack ('<16s', f.read(16))[0]
print 'dispvdn =' + str(value)
```

This is working fine and I am getting the expected value.  However when I print a value, of 6 chars for example, I see the entire string length of 16 like so.

dispvdn =40010◦◦◦◦◦◦◦◦◦◦◦

I am wondering if this is a lack of a \0.   What would be the best way to terminate or trim this correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. From your question, it looks like you're reading in 16 bytes and then writing out 16 bytes. Where are you trying to write out 6 bytes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unpacking a struct ending with an ASCIIZ string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850950/unpacking-a-struct-ending-with-an-asciiz-string)

Comment: The binary file definition has 16 bytes for a char[].  The string inside could be any length within that 16.  So my understanding is I have to pull all 16 and then create the string out of it.  When the value comes in short I am getting garbage to fill the 16.  I am looking to trim off this garbage and just get the characters that were present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing which works for what I needed. I created the following small method.

```
def finalizeString(data):   
    len = data.index('\0')
    return data[0:len]
```

This allows the following to work to get the string from the larger binary read.

```
value = struct.unpack ('<21s', f.read(21))[0]   
print 'ucid =' + finalizeString (str(value))
```

I know I can compress and clean this up but I wanted to share so this is marked as closed.

Comment: Hello, in StackOverflow questions are not "marked as closed". Actually, you should accept some answer as correct, even if it's your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this (similar to your own answer):

```
value = struct.unpack ('<16s', f.read(16))[0]
truncated = value.split('\0')[0]   ## split and take the first substring
print 'dispvdn =' + truncated
```